# Automatic Cloud Firestore Updating

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cloud, google-cloud-firestore

I have data under certain collections that I want to have deleted automatically based on how long the user chooses the data to be inputted in the database for.

Is there a specific google firebase/cloud firestore mechanism / method that I can apply, etc.

How would I go about doing so?

Comment: There is no built-in support for time-to-live in Cloud Firestore. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173560/is-there-any-ttl-time-to-live-for-documents-in-firebase-firestore

Answer (score 1):

How about scheduling **Cloud Functions**?

I didn't create such a mechanism but this seems suitable for your scenario. There's an article on the Google Blog about this approach: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html

Comment: How could I implement this in my app with Swift? Is there any way to do this without Python or Node.js?

Comment: There is no built-in support for time-to-live in Cloud Firestore. Cloud Functions run in Node.js only. You can find a [sample of this in the functions-samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-old-child-nodes).

Comment: So my cloud functions have to get the data from my firestore database (after getting the input from a user on my app) and then delete the entries through a function made in node js?

Comment: Yes, probably you'd like to separate this logic in a nodejs Cloud Function (some kind of backend for you). Making this mechanism in a Swift app doesn't seem like a good idea :)

Comment: @sarneeh We need our cloud function to be always monitoring the expiration time stamps of the entries in our Firestore database. The lowest time interval that we can use on a Cron job is 1 minute. Do you guys have any suggestions?