# Store temporary data (that automatically deletes after 1 minute) on Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, webrtc

I have an application where users keep writing data to the database that only needs to last for 1 minute. For example, Alice stores `{foo: bar}` at 10:36:00pm, and at 10:37:00pm, that entry should automatically be deleted from the database to free up memory, as it will never be used again.

Is there a way to do this, or do I have no choice but to manually have users delete their temp data after a minute? That wouldn't be ideal, because if a user "forgets" to (e.g. they lose their internet connection or close the app before they delete), then that entry will stay taking up space forever unless I set up a worker manually cleaning the database of these old entries.

For the record, the intended use case is to have Firestore act as a WebRTC signalling server, where users temporarily signal each other to establish a p2p connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, [there’s no such thing in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173560/is-there-any-ttl-time-to-live-for-documents-in-firebase-firestore). This mechanism is commonly described as TTL (Time To Live).

You can, however, [roll your own TTL mechanism using Cloud Tasks](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a).

For your use case, very “short-term”, heavy-rotation, ephemeral, and presumably small data, you may also consider Redis, which [has built-in TTL](https://redis.io/commands/ttl) and higher performance. Depending on your volume, may turn out cheaper as well.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting Redis! To have a redis-based database similar to Firestore, is the cheapest/best thing Amazon Elasticache? Or does firebae or any google product support Redis?

Comment: You’re welcome! Yes, there’s a managed Redis service in GCP called [Cloud Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore).